# Android adapter's getView() not calling an activity

Tags: java, android, adapter, getview

I am trying to call an activity from adapter class. My activity class has no constructor but `onCreate()`. How do I call it from `getView()`? I searched for solutions but it's not working.

My adapter `getView()`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //SharedPostView holder;
        PostActivity holder;



        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.d("network frag list"," convertView null ");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_post, null);
            holder = new PostActivity();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            Log.d("network frag list"," convertView.getTag() ");
            holder = (PostActivity)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.init(position);
        Log.d("network frag list", " getView");


        return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

This is my **getView** from adapter class,

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View myView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        try {

            if (myView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_affiliates_list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtAffiliateHeader = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtAffiliateHeader);

                holder.rlMain = (RelativeLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
                holder.viewLine = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.viewLine);

                myView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) myView.getTag();
            }
            holder.txtAffiliateHeader.setText(""+ AffiliatesList.get(position).getStrAffiliateTitle());

            holder.rlMain.setTag(position);
            holder.rlMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int arg2 = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return myView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return myView;
        }
    }
```

This is how you can call the activity from adapter class on click of your button or full relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to launch another activity from your listview. For that you need an intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MySecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

[Read more](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the accessibility of the method `startActivity()`. You can see the details of this method once you hit the `ctrl+click` in the `Android Studio`. Here is the detail , The class hierarchy up to Activity is as below-

```
Context (android.content)
   ContextWrapper (android.content)
     ContextThemeWrapper (android.view)
       Activity (android.app)
```

the `Context` class is having a abstract method.

```
 public abstract void startActivity(Intent intent);
```

This is overridden in the class `ContextWrapper` and the `Activity`.
Hence you can call the method `startActivity(Intent intent)` from any of the derived classes or from reference of the derived classes.

So you have are having reference of the `Context` you can call the method as-

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```